# Taking data from one table and inserting it into another MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a code of:

```
UPDATE graph AS s
JOIN (SELECT Player, (Score) AS newscore
  FROM scores
  GROUP BY Player) AS d
JOIN (SELECT Player, (Player) AS newplayer
  FROM scores
  GROUP BY Player) AS e
JOIN (SELECT curdate()) AS q
insert into s ( s.Score, s.Player, s.Date) values ( newplayer, newscore, q);
```

What I am trying to do is take data from one table and put it into the other.

The first table "graph" is where I want new data put into, it has three fields:

Date
Score
Player

The second table "scores" is where I want to take the data from, it has many fields but only two are of importance for this:

Player
Score

I want to take the data of the current day (Player and Score) and create a new line inside of "graph" using Player Score and CURDATE.

anyone know what I can do to make my code work? or maybe have a better idea for my code?

Thank you.

-edit-

Data in scores table

dem0n123 1220
Mordrah  1236
extcy    1245

What I want the new data in the graph table to look like

dem0n123 1220 2013-12-03
Mordrah  1236 2013-12-03
extcy    1245 2013-12-03

Comment: can you show more information maybe some data from each table and what you want the new row(s) in the graph table to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fd75/1)

```
CREATE TABLE scores
    (`name` varchar(25), `value` int)
;

INSERT INTO scores
    (`name`, `value`)
VALUES
    ('dem0n123', 1220),
    ('Mordrah', 1236),
    ('extcy', 1245)
;

CREATE TABLE graph
  (`name` varchar(25), 
   `value` int, 
   `mydate` DateTime);


insert into graph (name, value, mydate)
select name,value, CURDATE() from scores

select name,value,mydate from graph
```

Comment: there already is a table named scores, with all that data, and there is already a table named graph... i need to take the data from scores... and insert it into a new set of lines for each player in graph

Comment: I believe the answer is in there: 

insert into graph (name, value, mydate)
select name,value, CURDATE() from scores